# add math.round() to a form that user input fills out then clicks a button to see the output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have gotten the bulk of my code figured out but now am having issues with the syntax (yet again) on how to successfully validate that:

-it needs to be ONLY numbers allowed to type
-check for valid input and do not allow users to input values that will return NaN

-needs to round to a whole integer (ie, 79.8 suddenly becomes '80', 41.2 becomes 40 to figure out what grade later)

likely using math.round, I imagine, but I have been playing with this for hours and cannot figure out where I add "math.round" since it's a form and I suck at this. :(

```
<label>Homework Assignments</label>
<input type="number" id="hmwk" size=2 value="hmwk" oninput="validate(this)">
<br>
<label>Midterm Exam</label>
<input type="number" id="mdtm" size=2 value="mdtm" oninput="validate(this)">
<br>
<label>Final Exam</label>
<input type="number" id="final" size=2 value="final" oninput="validate(this)">
<br>
<label>Participation Points</label>
<input type="number" id="prtc" size=2 value="prtc" oninput="validate(this)">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="GPA" onclick="grade()" oninput="validate(this)">
<textarea id="output" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;" disabled></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function grade() {
var grd1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hmwk').value * 0.5);
var grd2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mdtm').value * 0.2);
var grd3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('final').value * 0.2);
var grd4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prtc').value * 0.1);
var total = grd1 + grd2 + grd3 + grd4;
var display = document.getElementById('output');
var msg = '';
var grade = 0;

switch (true) {
    case (total >= 90 && total <= 100):
        grade = "you got an A, wow I'm impressed!";
        break;
    case (total >= 80 && total <= 89):
        grade = "you got a B- pretty darn good!";
        break;
    case (total >= 70 && total <= 79):
        grade = "you got a C... but an A for effort!";
        break;
    case (total >= 60 && total <= 69):
        grade = "unfortunately you got a D and you have to retake the course.";
        break;
    case (total >= 0 && total <= 59):
        grade = "F.\r\nSorry you have to retake this course, try studying more next time.";
        break;
    default:
        grade = "F";
        break;
}

msg = "Your grade point average is " + total + " percent, which means you get an " + grade;
display.innerHTML = 'Your Final Grade Is: ' + total + "\r\n" + msg;
  }
</script>
```

when the user types their grades in each blank, I don't want the text field form boxes to allow them to type more than 2 numbers or 2 numbers with two decimals places. Example they can type:

23.56 (two numbers with two more separated by a decimal)

or

87.9 (two numbers with a decimal separator and another digit)

or

90

or

100 (max)

don't allow:

995 (three digits with no decimal passed 100 percent total allowed since this is a grade)

76.999

or

86.433254647447474 (too many numbers passed the decimal, overall)

101 (nothing over 100 allowed)

or

any letters whatsoever

or

any characters other than a decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when expecting a number with x decimals you can multiply by factors of 10 and round to trim any trailing numbers.

This makes it easier as you don't have to deal have to deal with the floats when comparing.

NOTE: I have changed your `oninput` event to `onchange` which will fire after changing the input

```js
function grade() {
    var grd1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hmwk').value * 0.5),
        grd2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mdtm').value * 0.2),
        grd3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('final').value * 0.2),
        grd4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prtc').value * 0.1),
        total = grd1 + grd2 + grd3 + grd4,
        display = document.getElementById('output'),
        msg = '',
        grade = 0;
        
    // round the total to 2 dp
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;

    switch (true) {
        case (total >= 90 && total <= 100):
            grade = "you got an A, wow I'm impressed!";
            break;
            
        case (total >= 80 && total <= 89):
            grade = "you got a B- pretty darn good!";
            break;
            
        case (total >= 70 && total <= 79):
            grade = "you got a C... but an A for effort!";
            break;
            
        case (total >= 60 && total <= 69):
            grade = "unfortunately you got a D and you have to retake the course.";
            break;
            
        case (total >= 0 && total <= 59):
            grade = "F.\r\nSorry you have to retake this course, try studying more next time.";
            break;
            
        default:
            grade = "F";
            break;
    }

    msg = "Your grade point average is " + total + " percent, which means you get an " + grade;
    display.innerHTML = 'Your Final Grade Is: ' + total + "\r\n" + msg;
}

function validate(ele){
  // times by 100 then round to 2dp to trim any trailing numbers
  // e.g. 24.696 => 2470
  var val = Math.round(ele.value * 100);
  
  // check if bad input or less than 0
  if(isNaN(val) || val < 0){
    ele.value = "0";
    return;
  }
  
  // divide by 100 to return to a number with up to 2dp
  // e.g. 2470 => 24.7
  val = val / 100;
   
  // check if greater than 100
  if(val > 100){
    ele.value = "100";
    return;
  }
  
  ele.value = val;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Homework Assignments</label>
  <input type="number" id="hmwk" size=2 value="hmwk" onchange="validate(this)">
  <br>
  <label>Midterm Exam</label>
  <input type="number" id="mdtm" size=2 value="mdtm" onchange="validate(this)">
  <br>
  <label>Final Exam</label>
  <input type="number" id="final" size=2 value="final" onchange="validate(this)">
  <br>
  <label>Participation Points</label>
  <input type="number" id="prtc" size=2 value="prtc" onchange="validate(this)">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="GPA" onclick="grade()" onchange="validate(this)">
  <textarea id="output" style="height: 50px; width: 100%;" disabled></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use step and define the range for any input with type of number as bellow

```
 <input id="" name="" type="number" min="0.00" max="100.00" placeholder="85.00" class="" step="1.00">
```

Comment: thank you for this tip. i clearly wasn't aware it was so simple